# if $19a^2 \equiv b^2 \pmod 7$ then $19a^2 \equiv b^2 \pmod {7^2}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, quadratic-residues, quadratic-reciprocity

I am stuck with this problem. All what I can tell is that $19a^2 \equiv 5a^2 \equiv b^2 \pmod 7$ and $5$ is not a quadratic residue$\pmod 7$. Any hints please,,

Comment: Right, $5$ is not a quadratic residue $\pmod 7$.  So the only way to solve $5a^2\equiv b^2 \pmod 7$ is?

Comment: @lulu not sure how to proceed further, can you elaborate a little more. I guess that $5a^2$ both shall be a quadratic residue mod 7.

Comment: Ah, but the product of a non-residue and a non-zero residue is a non-residue.  So that implies....

Comment: that implies $a^2$ is a quadratic residue. right?

Comment: Well, $a^2$ is obviously a quadratic residue (it's written as a square after all).  But which quadratic residue is it?  It can't be $1$, say, since $19\times 1$ is not a residue.  It can't be $4$  since $19\times 4$ is not a residue.  In fact there's only one possible value for $a^2 \pmod 7$.

Comment: Note:   this is kind of a trick question.  The claim is perfectly true but not for very interesting reasons.  You got the main point when you noticed that $5$ isn't a square $\pmod 7$.

Comment: @lulu,  $a^2$ cannot be $2$ as well. This implies that $b^2\equiv 3 \pmod 7$ which is not true. Hence, $a^2 \equiv 0$. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Absolutely.  And this works for any prime, not just $7$.  Here we get $7\,|\,a$ which immediately tells us that $7\,|\,b$ and the rest is easy.

Comment: Ahaa,, Thanks,, I really appreciate this great help @lulu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $a$ is nonzero on $\Bbb Z_7$, so it has an inverse $a^{-1}$. Then $\overline 5 \equiv {(a^{-1})}^2b^2 \equiv (a^{-1}b)^2 \equiv c^2$. But $5$ is not a quadratic residue modulo 7, so...

Comment: Could the downvoter please explain why?

Comment: so, $7|c^2$. Is that right?

Comment: @MagedSaeed not exactly, but yes. This tells us that if $a$ was nonzero, we would get a contradiction. So it must be zero.

Comment: By the way, your way is elegant. I do not know why it got downvoted?!